# How to reassign uploaded files to some other models rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, carrierwave

I have a scenario where i am uploading files dynamically using ajax `remotipart`, then later i assign those uploaded files to any model. I have such settings in uploader.

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.pluralize.underscore}/#{model.documentable_type.to_s.pluralize.underscore}/#{model.documentable_id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(doc pdf docx xls xlsx)
  end
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :document, DocumentUploader
  belongs_to :documentable, :polymorphic => true

  validates :document, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :documents, :as=>:documentable
end
```

When i upload a document without providing `documentable` source, it uploads the files to `/uploads/documents/uploaded_file.doc`

But when i assign that document to some other model like

```
@post = Post.first
@post.documents << Document.last
@post.save
```

It save the record correctly and when get url of the file like `@post.documents.first.document.url` it gave url like this `/uploads/documents/posts/10212/uploaded_file.doc` where the file was not available.

How can i handle such assignment of pre-existing uploads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing lot of hit and trail. but finally solved.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :document, DocumentUploader
  belongs_to :documentable, :polymorphic => true

  validates :document, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true

  after_update :relocate_files

  def relocate_files
    src_file = Rails.root.join("public", "uploads", "documents", document.url.split("/").last)
    dst_file = Rails.root.join("public", "uploads", "documents", documentable_type.pluralize.underscore, documentable_id.to_s, document.url.split("/").last)
    unless FileTest.exists?(dst_file)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(dst_file))
      FileUtils.mv(src_file, dst_file)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I came here while googling and thought some people might help this piece of code I'm using in a controller to re-assign a file (here it's an image) to another model which is handled with CarrierWave:

```
def create
  temporary_image = TemporaryImage.find(params[:temporary_image][:id])
  @player = Player.new(params[:player])
  @player.image = File.open(temporary_image.image.current_path)
  # now you can handle @player.image as if it was
  # originally assigned by CarrierWave
end
```

where

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  mount_uploader :image, PlayerImageUploader
end
```

and

```
class TemporaryImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image
  mount_uploader :image, TemporaryImageUploader
end
```

I'm using this in conjunction with an ajax [fileupload](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload) (stored via `TemporaryImage`) where the image is immediately presented and can then be [cropped](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised). After cropping it is stored within `Player`.